# syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach'

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I can't seem to find the syntax error. here is the problematic code:

```
<div class='related_row'>
                    <?php
                        foreach($postList as $post):
                            setup_postdata( $post ); 
                    ?>
                            <div class='related_product'>
                                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                    <div class='related_image'>
                                        <a class='service_overlay' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></a>
                                        <a class='service_page' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <div class='related_image'>
                                        <a class='service_overlay' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'></a>
                                        <a class='service_page' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><img src="<?php get_bloginfo() ?>/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/header_image.png" alt='Service image' /></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class='related_title'>
                                    <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php $counter++; ?>
                            <?php if($counter % 3 == 0 && $counter < $total ): ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class='related_row'>
                            <? endif; ?>
                            <?php
                                endforeach;
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>
                    </div>
```

I've been staring at this bit of code for the past 20 minutes and can't seem to spot it. I would really appreciate it if someone could point it out please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've not got "short tags" switched on, the error is on line 26 of the sample above:

```
<? endif; ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You got it spot on. cant beleive i missed that. i was staring at that same peice of code for so long!. thank you!!